# Parallel port not working with an HP Laserjet 6P

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp

I'm working on setting up an old printer (HP LaserJet 6P) on some old hardware (Gateway E4300) running Precise (12.04 LTS).  When I try to select the parallel port in `hp-setup -i`, it gives me the following error:

```
$ sudo hp-setup -i

--------------------------------
| SELECT CONNECTION (I/O) TYPE |
--------------------------------

  Num       Connection  Description
            Type
  --------  ----------  ----------------------------------------------------------
  0*        usb         Universal Serial Bus (USB)
  1         net         Network/Ethernet/Wireless (direct connection or JetDirect)
  2         par         Parallel Port (LPT:)

Enter number 0...2 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? 2

Using connection type: par

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

Things I've checked so far:

1) The printer is plugged in and connected.

2) The printer is turned on.

3) The parallel port is enabled in the BIOS.

4) The parallel port mode is not set in the BIOS (no option to do so).

5) The parallel port modules are loaded.  Output of lsmod, trimmed to relevant bits:

```
wdmartin@woot:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ppdev                  12850  0
lp                     17456  0
parport                40931  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
parport_pc             32115  1
```

6) `/dev/lp0` and `/dev/parport0` exist:

```
$ ls -hal /dev/lp0 /dev/parport0
crw-rw---- 1 root lp  6, 0 Aug 15 11:58 /dev/lp0
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 99, 0 Aug 15 11:58 /dev/parport0
```

7) My user is a member of the lp and lpadmin groups:

```
$ groups
wdmartin adm lp cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

8) `dmesg` shows the parallel port driver loaded:

```
[   17.206314] parport_pc 00:08: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   17.206349] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE,EPP]
[   17.317279] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[   17.527946] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
```

9) `lspci` **does not** show the parallel port:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82915G/P/GV/GL/PL/910GL Memory Controller Hub (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 04)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82915G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FR (ICH6/ICH6R) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FW (ICH6/ICH6W) SATA Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8050 PCI-E ASF Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 17)
05:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 (rev 61)
```

Why doesn't the parallel port show up in lspci?  Does that mean the parallel port is not working, despite everything else looking good?

I've tried configuring the printer via CUPS rather than using `hp-setup`, and it appeared to accept the settings, and take a print job, but no actual printing occurred.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: We never did figure this out.  Problem was resolved by ditching the ancient printer in favor of a newer one, which worked immediately.  Could a mod please close the question now?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So see you state that your user is a member of the lp group.

What does that line look like in /etc/group?

That will let us know for sure if the user is a member of the group or not.